# Want to modify the display value of some SidebarFacet topic in Dspace 4.x XMLUI

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

[image: SidebarFacet of Dspace 4.x XMLUI]

In the above picture,in the 'Language' portion,languages are shown as **'en', 'es'** etc. I want to display it like **'English','Spanish'** etc. 
To do this, I have change the following portion of [dspace-install]/config/input-forms.xml file ->

```html
<value-pairs value-pairs-name="common_iso_languages" dc-term="language_iso">
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>English</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>english</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Assamese</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>assamese</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Hindi</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>hindi</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Bengali</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>bengali</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Marathi</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>marathi</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Tamil</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>tamil</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Orisa</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>orisa</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>Kannada</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>kannada</stored-value>
     </pair>
     <pair>
       <displayed-value>(Other)</displayed-value>
       <stored-value>other</stored-value>
     </pair>
   </value-pairs>
```

I have change the all <**stored-value**>, now after doing the change, the **'display value'** of **'Language'** portion of **sidebar facet** is not changed for already submitted items, if i do submit any items after changing the **input-forms.xml**,only for that item it is reflecting. But i want to change for all submitted items also. How can it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes you made in your input-forms are not retroactive for submitted items (ie, the values were already set), you should use [Batch Metadata Editing](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Batch+Metadata+Editing) instead. Then reindex your dspace.

Comment: It works. After doing that reindex is not needed.  Thank you very much @euler.